# how to validate datalist field by using jquery validator in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, datalist

Hi I am working as web application developer, I am stuck in the jquery validation. In my form have to show list employee by using  tag in my form, if the client may be enter the correct name or enter few char and select the employee name from datalist. Suppose the client enter any name (except exist employee name from list), have to validate.

my html code:

```
<input list="pAdminID" id="pAdminName" name="pAdminName" onchange="GetID()" value="<?php echo $pAdminName; ?>">
<datalist name="pAdminID" id="pAdminID">
<?php foreach($emp as $row) { ?>
<option id="<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?>"><?php } ?>
</datalist>
<input type="hidden" id="empID" name="empID">
```

my script :
to get employee id

```
function GetID() {  
    var x = $('#pAdminName').val();
    var z = $('#pAdminID');
    var val = $(z).find('option[value="' + x + '"]');
    var empID = document.getElementById('empID');
    empID.value  = val.attr('id');
}
```

to validation:

```
$(function() {

    $("#project").validate({

    rules: {
        pName: "required",
        pAdminName: "required"
    },     

    messages: {
        pName: "Please enter the Project Name",
        pAdminName: "Please enter or select the Assignment name"
    }
});
});
```

please help how to validate the pAdminName field?

Comment: ummmm.. how exactly do you want to validate.. ?? you got a select with options. the user choses one of them. that#s it??

Comment: this datalist tag is not show like dropdownlist box, It show like normal textbox, so user can enter any name

Comment: then change your input to `select` and let the name be "adminName" or whatever

Comment: I know that but my client ask like datalist... what can i do?

Comment: you could make it look like datalist, but prevent manual input..

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("adminName", function(value, element) {
//process/validate here

    return value;);
}, "Must admin name");
```

And then applying this like so:

```
$('#project').validate({
    rules : {
        pAdminName: { adminName: true }
    }
});
```

Comment: where i can add this " jQuery.validator.addMethod("adminName", function(value, element)" ? will you please little brief

Comment: hi i am not much familiar in jquery i can understand your reply, I want know i have get the emp_id in following script, so here i can validate the user enter exist employee or unknown employee? `function GetID() {  
    var x = $('#pAdminName').val();
    var z = $('#pAdminID');
    var val = $(z).find('option[value="' + x + '"]');
    var empID = document.getElementById('empID');
    empID.value  = val.attr('id');
}`                                                                  so will tell how to validate here ?

Comment: so you want to validate the employee ID if it exist in your db?

Comment: yes but not in db, b'coz i already get and store in the client side. the emp_id store in the datalist pAdminID value....